# Can't count string's (array's) length in TASM. Loop ends work

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

```
DATA SEGMENT
    STRING DB "ABCDE", 0    
DATA ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT STACK
    DW 100 DUP(?)
SSEG ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE, DS: DATA, SS:SSEG
    
START:
    XOR AX, AX

    MOV SI, OFFSET STRING ; SI ---> FIRST STRING MEMBER IN THIS SPECIFIC PROGRAMM. 
                          ;         USED TO COUNT STRING'S LENGTH
    DEC SI

    ;COUNTING STRING'S LENGTH
    WHILE:INC SI 
          CMP STRING[SI], 0
          JNZ WHILE
    MOV AX, SI ;AX => 5H
        
        
        
    
EXIT:MOV AH, 4CH
     INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Loop ends his work when SI = 2 (STRING[SI] == STRING[2] == "C" == 43H).
When SI = 2, ZF = 1.
Why it happens?

(I used `DEC SI` before loop because first instruction into the loop increases SI. Like do-while loop. It used to avoid ZF changing by INC if it was after CMP).

Comment: `SI` is already a pointer since you did `MOV SI, OFFSET STRING`. As such, `CMP STRING[SI], 0` is wrong, because it's adding `STRING` again. Since you want `SI` to be a counter, do `XOR SI, SI` to zero it instead of loading with the address.

Comment: What does it mean "adding `STRING` again"?

Comment: `STRING[SI]` means `[STRING+SI]` but since `SI=STRING` that is then `[STRING+STRING]` (first time around).

Comment: Even if I do `MOV SI, 0` and then count string's length -> the loop stops on SI = 2 because ZF being = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ASSUME CS:CODE, DS: DATA, SS:SSEG
> ```

It's not enough to just `ASSUME`. In the case of the `DS` segment register, you need to make it happen with the appropriate code. At program start the `DS` segment register does not automatically point at your `DATA SEGMENT`.

```
mov ax, @DATA
mov ds, ax
```

Your loop was scanning the program's PSP and stopped at the third byte because that happened to be zero. {CDh, 20h, 00h, A0h, ... }

---

The other error was that you double referenced the string with these instructions:

```
MOV SI, OFFSET STRING    1x
CMP STRING[SI], 0        2x
```

This error was [noticed by Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594606/cant-count-strings-arrays-length-in-tasm-loop-ends-work#comment110694567_62594606)

When you will have corrected both errors, next code will produce `SI=5`:

```
START:
    mov ax, @DATA
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, -1
WHILE:
    inc si
    cmp STRING[si], 0
    jne WHILE
    ; SI=5
```